# Calling javascript on blazor server side

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

How can i call javascript in a blazor server application? I am trying to follow this document

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/aede436b-4c57-4551-a7b4-a005f2aed499.aspx

On my ui.razor file i created the following code

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
...
private async void callWidgetApplication()
{
    var fetched = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("fetchComponenent", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
}
```

I create a file on my wwwroot call Widget.js. this is what i have for the moment

```
function fetchComponenent() {
    return true;
}
```

But i keep getting an error on my invokeasync.

```
CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.JSInterop.DotNetObjectReference<InfoAccessBlz.Pages.InfoAccess>' to 'object?[]?'
```

The whole reason in using javascript is to call an other website using ajax. So maybe if there is a better way, this is not an api, but its to retrieve an html site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("fetchComponenent");
```

Your JavaScript Function doesn't accept any parameter and add the JavaScript file to the _Host.cshtml like this

```
<script src="~/Widget.js"></script>
```